# if $p$ is prime, then the nonzero elements of $ℤ_p$ form a group of order $p-1$ multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I defined  $ℤ^*_p = \big\{\overline{a}∈ℤ _p\vert \overline{a}≠0\big\}$.The order of $ℤ_p$ is $p$ so $ℤ^*_p $ has order $p-1$ since it excludes only one element.

The smallest prime is $2$ thus each $ℤ^*_p $ has at least one element so it is nonempty.for example $ℤ^*_2 =\big\{[1]\big\}$.we know the greatest common divisor always exists .Furthermore this theorem states $(a,p)=1$ if $p∤a$ and $(a,p)=p$ if $p∣a$.By assumption $\overline{a}≠\overline{0}$ thus $p∣a$ so $(a,p)=1$. now take $\overline{a}$ and $\overline{b}$ in $ℤ^*_p$ .

Suppose their product $\overline{a}\overline{b}=\overline{ab}=\overline{0}$ . as we know $p$ and $a$ are relatively prime. thuw $ab≡0 \left(\operatorname{mod}\ p\right)$ so $ p∣ab$ and since $(a,p)=1$ then $p∣b$ .
This contradicts the assumption $\overline{b}≠\overline{0}$ thus $\overline{ab}≠\overline{0}$,therefore $\overline{ab}∈ ℤ^*_p$.

Since multiplication module $p$ is well-defined in $ℤ_p$ and now seen as closed in $ℤ^*_p$. it is well-defined as a binary operator in $ℤ^*_p$.Furthermore it inherits the associativity so it is a semigroup.

since $p ∤1$,$\overline{1}≠\overline{0}$ for any $p$ , so $\overline{1}∈ℤ^*_p$ . $\overline{a}\overline{b}=\overline{ab}=\overline{ba}=\overline{b}\overline{a}$ using the
commutativity of multiplication in integers. From here the conclusion is simpler:$\overline{a}\overline{1}=\overline{a1}=\overline{a}$ , forcing $ \overline{1}$ to be the identity of $ℤ^*_p$. 
Given any $a ∈ ℤ^*_p$, $a^m ∈ ℤ^*_p$, for or all $m∈ ℤ^+$, since $ℤ^*_p$ is closed to products.

Since the set is finite $a^m ≡a^n \left(\operatorname{mod}\ p\right)$ for some $m$ and $n$,which $m≠n$,or
otherwise there would be infinitely many elements. Without loss of generality
let $m<n$. using the fact $(a,p)=1$ so $(a^m,p)=1$ .we conclude $1≡a^{n-m}\left(\operatorname{mod}\ p\right)$

the questions is that:

i) why if $a^m∈ℤ^*_p$,this is right just for all $m∈ ℤ^+$, it's clear that $m∉ℤ^-$ but if $m=0$ then $a^m=a^0=1∈ℤ^*_p$ since $1 ∈ \overline{1}$  and  $\overline{1}∈ℤ^*_p $

ii) and the **most** important is that how it can be a group??

Comment: Posted yesterday on MO, apparently by a different user: https://mathoverflow.net/q/336216/30186

Comment: What is unclear about ii)?

Comment: If $gcd(a^m,p) = 1$, then $p$ does not divide $a^m$, so does not divide $a$. Then $gcd(a,p) = 1$ and in particular $\gcd(a^{n-m},p) = 1$. For the finiteness question, please just work through the definition. I am sure you will figure it out.

Comment: Oh, I misread your question. I added an edit to my answer.

Comment: Some newlines and spaces would make this much more legible.

Comment: well, i) is just a consequence of mapping an infinite set on a finite one ($\mathbb{Z}^+ \to \mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}p^*$ ), so including the zero does not change anything since you can safely find 2 nontrivial $m,n$ (you got infinetely many).
ii) this is litterary the definition.
iii) you just proved that it is a group

Comment: well, they forget closedness, but otherwise it works out, so assume that multiplicatio is closed, then you get associativity and unit for free, so all you need is inverses, and that is what they prove.

Answer (score 1):

i) In the end you need to remember conventions. For integers, the conventions are
$$
a^0 = 1, a^n = a a^{n-1}, \quad n \in \mathbb Z_+.
$$
If $n<0$, $a^{-1}$ will not be an integer, so this is not how it's interpreted in $\mathbb Z_p^*$. Instead, we set $\bar{a}^{-1}$ to be the unique equivalence class $\bar b$ in $\mathbb Z_p^*$ satisfying $ab \equiv 1 (mod \, p)$. Then you can define $\bar{a}^{-n} =(\bar{a}^{-1})^n$.

ii) There are finitely many elements in $\mathbb Z_p$, namely the equivalence classes of $0,1,...,p-1$. The group you're considering just doesn't include $0$, so of course it is also finite. :)

iii) You've just proved that multiplication of equivalence classes is associative, has the neutral element $\bar 1$ and each element has an inverse. Isn't that what a group is? (You even proved that it's an abelian group!)

Comment: assume $Z^*3={[1],[2]}$ and $\left[1\right]=\left\{...,-5,-2,1,4,...\right\},\left[2\right]=\left\{...,-4,-1,2,5,...\right\}$ cannot I say $Z^*3=\big\{{...,−5,−2,1,4,−4,−1,2..,}\big\} $? in this way we have an infinite set

Comment: You just wrote $\mathbb Z_3^* = {[1],[2]}$. This means that this set has two elements. In set theory, everything is a set. Elements of a set are also sets. You don't think of it this way, but even the integers you know and love are defined as sets. So this means that $[1]$ and $[2]$ are also sets. But the number of elements in the sets $[1]$ and $[2]$ has nothing to do with the number of elements in the set ${[1],[2]}$, because the latter only contains those two sets as elements!